# How to add two list - one with the positive sign, one with the negative sign

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```
2
[-0.09891464 -0.09715325 -0.09410605 -0.09019411 -0.0860636  -0.08205132
 -0.07875871 -0.07614547 -0.07443062 -0.07346302 -0.07298417 -0.07290273
 -0.07287797 -0.07287593 -0.07287593] code_length
[-0.98949882 -0.97240346 -0.94268702 -0.90432065 -0.86363176 -0.82404481
 -0.79160852 -0.76596087 -0.74920381 -0.73978155 -0.73512854 -0.73433788
 -0.73409758 -0.7340778  -0.7340778 ] code_length
[-0.08209141  0.24530752  0.57179519  0.89738478  1.22269259  1.54813354
  1.87437147  2.20121635  2.52864319  2.85637075  3.18420369  3.51207073
  3.83993948  4.16780833  4.49567718] code_length
[0.09891464 0.09715325 0.09410605 0.09019411 0.0860636  0.08205132
 0.07875871 0.07614547 0.07443062 0.07346302 0.07298417 0.07290273
 0.07287797 0.07287593 0.07287593] code_length
[-0.98949882 -0.97240346 -0.94268702 -0.90432065 -0.86363176 -0.82404481
 -0.79160852 -0.76596087 -0.74920381 -0.73978155 -0.73512854 -0.73433788
 -0.73409758 -0.7340778  -0.7340778 ] code_length
[-0.08209141  0.24530752  0.57179519  0.89738478  1.22269259  1.54813354
  1.87437147  2.20121635  2.52864319  2.85637075  3.18420369  3.51207073
  3.83993948  4.16780833  4.49567718] code_length


print(len(pos_list))
print(streamline_x[0])
print(streamline_y[0])
print(streamline_z[0])
print(streamline_x[1])
print(streamline_y[1])
print(streamline_z[1])
```

I would like to plot them, and I would like to plot them with the negative z-component. It provides these two cycles:

```
for i in range(len(pos_list)):
    ax.plot3D(streamline_x[i], streamline_y[i], streamline_z[i], color=cfg._sections['colors'].get('mag_field'), linewidth=cfg._sections['styles'].get('lines'))

for i in range(len(pos_list)):
    ax.plot3D(streamline_x[i], streamline_y[i], -streamline_z[i], color=cfg._sections['colors'].get('mag_field'), linewidth=cfg._sections['styles'].get('lines'))
```

However, I would like to simplify it and create 3 lists for plotting instead of 6. I tried the following:

```
minus_streamline_z1 = []
minus_streamline_z2 = []

# Create a function that multiplies each element in list by (-1)
for x in streamline_z[0].tolist():
    minus_streamline_z1.append(x * (-1))

for x in streamline_z[1].tolist():
    minus_streamline_z2.append(x * (-1))

minus_streamline_z = [minus_streamline_z1, minus_streamline_z2]


# Adding symmetric parts of streamline to plot them
for i in range(len(pos_list)):
    xs = streamline_x[i].tolist() + streamline_x[i].tolist()
    ys = streamline_y[i].tolist() + streamline_y[i].tolist()
    zs = streamline_z[i].tolist() + minus_streamline_z[i]
    ax.plot3D(xs, ys, zs)
```

What is wrong, please?

The first two cycles give this figure:

[image]

and the second way gives some strange line

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you currently have the first list start at `(-0.09891464, -0.98949882, -0.08209141)` and move up in the z-direction to `(-0.07287593, -0.7340778, 4.49567718)`. When you join the two lists together, it then jumps to  `(-0.09891464, -0.98949882, 0.08209141)`, before moving down in the z-direction to `(-0.07287593, -0.7340778, -4.49567718)`.

This jump where the lists join leads to the straight line segment you see in the second figure.

To solve this, you could reverse the order of the first of the two lists (using `[::-1]` to index the list) as you join them together.

For example:

```
for i in range(2):
    xs = streamline_x[i].tolist()[::-1] + streamline_x[i].tolist()
    ys = streamline_y[i].tolist()[::-1] + streamline_y[i].tolist()
    zs = streamline_z[i].tolist()[::-1] + minus_streamline_z[i]
    ax.plot3D(xs, ys, zs)
```

Produces:

[image]

Note there is still a small linear segment as you are jumping back up from `z=-0.08209141` to `z=0.08209141` where the two lists join, but for this particular plot that doesn't seem to be noticible.